# Add qtwebkit to qtcreator on a mac

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebkit

I have installed qt creator on my mac. I want to create a mobile html5 project using the qtwebkit. I dont know how to add the qtwebkit to qt creator. I have tried to google it but i can't find clear steps on how to do this. When I try to create the project it says no valid kits found.

I'm new to qt.
Thx for any help.

Comment: Did you get answer for this ?

Comment: No, I don't need it anymore but maybe it will help someone else.